# Escritura y lectura de ficheros serializar un array

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
package Exercici2;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Comarca implements Serializable {

    private String nom;
    private int habitants;

    public Comarca (String nom, int habitants){
        this.nom=nom;
        this.habitants=habitants;
    }
    public Comarca(){
        this.nom=null;
    }//Dar valor
    public void setNom(String comarca){nom=comarca;}
    public void setHabitants(int poblacio){ habitants=poblacio;}
    //COncultar valor
    public String getNom(){ return nom;}
    public int getHabitants(){return habitants;}

// ESCRIBIR FICHERO
    public static void EscriureFitxerObject () throws IOException , ClassNotFoundException{
        File f=new File("Datos.txt"); // Creamos el archivo
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        String comarca[] ={"Baixa Camp", "Segarra", "Bages", "Priorat", "Terra Alta",
            "Montsià", "Alt Camp","Anoia", "Maresme"};

        int poblacio[] = {190249, 22713, 184403, 9550, 12119, 69613, 44578, 117842, 437919};  

        oos.writeObject(comarca);

        oos.writeObject(poblacio);
        oos.close();
    }

   //LECTURA FICHERO! 
    public static void LlegirFitxerObject() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
        ObjectInputStream ois=null;
        try{

        File f=new File("datos.txt");
        FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(f);
        ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        while(true){
        //   ?????????????????          
        }            
        }catch(IOException io){
               System.out.println("Fin");
        }finally{
            ois.close();
               }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
            EscriureFitxerObject();
            LlegirFitxerObject();
    } }
```

Tengo problemas con la lectura no sé como hacerlo, creo que la escritura está bien a no ser que me digáis lo contrario.

Necesito leer el archivo que acabo de escribir.

¿Me podéis ayudar?

Para la escritura estoy obligada a utilizar ObjectOutputStream
Para la lectura estoy obligada a usar ObjectInputStream.

Comment: Primero si implementas serializable tienes que ponerle el numero se seria es un atributo privado final entero largo y su nombre serialVersionUID y le das un valor, luego para escribir cuando inicializas el objeto de ObjectOutputStream tiene que sobreescribir el metodo de la clase writeHearder y dejarlo en blanco, ya que ese metodo por defecto escribe una cabecera en el archivo txt, que da problemas al leer a partir del segundo elemento, y al igual en el objeto de la clase ObjectInputStream tienes que sobreescribir el metodo readerHeader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que esto te servira

el problema esta en que es al usar el `ObjectOutputStream` y escribir un objecto `oos.writeObject(...);` estas indicando que en el archivo solo abra un objeto y de ese tipo por lo que para escribir otro tendria que ser de otro tipo por ejemplo  double `oos.writeDouble(0);` para que estos queden separados la solucion que implemente en el codigo es agregar los dos objetos **comarca,poblaci** en un `ArrayList<Object> woi = new ArrayList<>();`  asi almacene esos 2 en el array para luego llamar solo ese objeto asi `ois.readObject();`

al final el array te traera los 2 objetos **comarca,poblacio** en arreglos como los definiste y bueno.. ya depende de ti como quieras usarlos.

```
public static void EscriureFitxerObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    File f = new File("{ruta_archivo}\\Datos.txt"); 
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    ArrayList<Object> woi = new ArrayList<>();

    String comarca[] = {"Baixa Camp", "Segarra", "Bages", "Priorat", "Terra Alta",
        "Montsià", "Alt Camp", "Anoia", "Maresme"};

    int poblacio[] = {190249, 22713, 184403, 9550, 12119, 69613, 44578, 117842, 437919};

    woi.add(comarca);
    woi.add(poblacio);

    oos.writeObject(woi);
    oos.close();
}
```

//---

```
public static void LlegirFitxerObject() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {

        File f = new File("{ruta_archivo}\\Datos.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ArrayList<Object> i = null;
        i = (ArrayList<Object>)ois.readObject();

        String[] comarca = (String[]) i.get(0);
        int[] poblacion = (int[]) i.get(1);

        for (int j : poblacion) {
            System.out.println(j);
        }
        System.out.println("------------------");
        for (String string : comarca) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io.getMessage());
    } finally {
        ois.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: esto es lo que quería! Mil gracias, pero tengo una duda al final de la lectura me da este error: [[Ljava.lang.String;@4dd8dc3, [I@6d03e736]

Comment: a lo siento no es un error, fue un system.out que deje mientras probaba :-) , no supone ninguna prioridad en el programa, esta debajo de la impresión de comarca   `System.out.println(i);`

Comment: ya lo veo! Tengo otra duda más, por entender el código por que me muestra antes las poblaciones y luego las comarcas? COn esto no molesto más promesita! xD

Comment: seria invertir esto no? for (int j : poblacion) {
            System.out.println(j);
        }
        System.out.println("------------------");
        for (String string : comarca) {
            System.out.println(string);

Comment: si asi es cada `foreach` se esta encargando de imprimir el valor de comarca y poblacion es solo invertirlo 

`for (int j : comarca) {
            System.out.println(j);
        }

        System.out.println("------------------");

        for (String string : poblacion) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Solución: Lee el contenido del archivo en el mismo orden que fue escrito.

Entrando en detalle, al revisar el método `EscriureFitxerObject`, tienes el siguiente código:

```
String comarca[] = ...
int poblacio[] = ...
//escribes un arreglo de String
oos.writeObject(comarca);
//escribes un arreglo de primitivos
oos.writeObject(poblacio);
```

Entonces, en tu método de lectura `LlegirFitxerObject` debes leer tal cual:

```
//lees el arreglo de String
String[] comarca = (String[]) ois.readObject();
//lees el arreglo de primitivos
int[] poblacio = (int[]) ois.readObject();
//no es necesario leer "eternamente"
//while (true) { 
//}
```

¿Cuándo leerías el contenido de un archivo binario "eternamente", o en otras palabras, usando `while(true)`? Haces esto **sí y solo sí** escribiste el archivo con un número desconocido de objetos (de preferencia de la misma clase). La validación que ofrece Java para estos casos es que, si se encuentra al final del archivo, entonces al tratar de leer lanzará una excepción del tipo [`EOFException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html). Un ejemplo:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = ... //escribe a un archivo X
String[] datos = { "hola", "mundo" };
//cantidad de elementos escritos "desconocida"
for (String s : datos) {
    oos.writeObject(s);
}

//...

ObjectInputStream ois = ... //leyendo del archivo X
//puesto que no sabes cuántos elementos hay, conviene usar una lista
List<String> datos = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    datos.add((String)ois.readObject());
} catch (EOFException e) {
    //fin del archivo
    System.out.println("Fin del archivo. No más contenido");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error desconocido. Revisar.");
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
System.out.println(datos);
```

Comment: gracias Luiggi ahora entiendo el tema del While!!